# Product Model with type and subtypes Django 1.10

Tags: django, database, django-models

I need to create a product model that has multiples types and type has multiples subtypes

I will share my models code and please someone tell me if I'm going in a good way.

```
class productCatalog(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})


class productType(models.Model):
    productID = models.ForeignKey(productCatalog)
    typeName = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class product_subType(models.Model):
    typeID = models.ForeignKey(productType)
    subType_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
```

This is the final result that I want to get:

### Product name

- Type 1:

  - Sub Type 1
  - Sub Type 2
  - Sub Type 3
- Type 2:

  - Sub Type 1
  - Sub Type 2

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, a `productCatalog` may have multiple `productType`, and a `productType` may have multiple `product_subType`.

This is a common way to approach the many-to-one association in django models.

Comment: Well you have created:
`
master group 1
 - group a
    - subgroup 1
    - subgroup 2
  - group b
    - ...
- master group 2
  - group a
    - subgroup 1
    - subgroup 2 ...
`

Comment: I tested on my project and works fine. Thanks for the support. :)